# How can you use the single elements of the row / columns from the CSV file to Javascript and use them as a variable to use in the code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, csv, variables

Title says the question but to be more specific and using an example given:

- | Name | Surname | Age |
- | Robert | Red | 25

and I want to use the name Robert in the code like a variable but to export it from the CSV file. (so something like csv.name[1])
I've been studying for 2/3 months now so I'm totally a beginner. I've been searching online or in forums but couldn't find anything.
Let me know if there's something confusing.
Have a wonderful day all.

Edit* and then you can do like

- var name = csv.name[1]
- console.log(name)

And by editing the name automatically will change the output.

Answer (score 0):

Since this post is tagged with `node.js`, I'm going to assume that you are actually using it.

Javascript doesn't have any built-in ways to directly access rows and columns from a csv file. You have to firstly parse the csv file into a type which Javascript can understand.

That being said, your best bet might be installing the [following npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv) (or just the csv-parse subpackage).

If you don't want to install additional npm packages, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14991797/13782419). It's a simple Javascript function that allows you to parse a csv file into an array which you can access like you mentioned in your question (`array[row][column]`).

Answer (score -1):

You might look at [d3-dsv](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv) (delimiter seperated values) part of the [d3](https://d3js.org/) library.

```js
const csvInput = "Name,Surname,Age\nRobert,Red,25\nJudith,Gray,29"

const parsed = d3.csvParse(csvInput);

console.log(parsed[0].Name);

console.log(parsed);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-dsv@3"></script>
```